# Visual Studio on Parallels: Installing Universal Windows Tools

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, parallels

I'm running Windows (64bit) in Parallels Desktop 12. I have Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 installed.

When I try to Install the features required for developing UWP apps, I go through the entire setup process and get a success message. But when I open VS up again, it says the features I just installed are not installed.

I've installed missing features dozens of times now and still nothing. I've reinstalled VS (Enterprise and Community) and still nothing.

What am I missing??

Comment: have you enabled the Virtualizatin in Parallels tools?

Comment: I haven't. I'll try.